# Get a color in between two given colors and a percentage

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get a color in between 2 colors and a percentage using js?
What I have is this:

```
let colorOne = {
 r: 240,
 g: 0, 
 b: 0
}
let colorTwo = {
 r: 255, 
 g: 255,
 b: 255
}
let percentageZero = 0
let percentageFifty = 0.5
let percentageOne = 1
```

Now for percentageZero, I would like to get a white color.
For percentageFifty, it would be a color in between the 2 colors (a sort of light red)
For percentageOne, it should be the original color, so rgb(240, 0, 0)

Note these are the 3 basic cases and could be getting any sort of percentages such as 55% or 20% etc.

Comment: C++ question, but I think this is what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488957/interpolate-from-one-color-to-another

Comment: What is the question here? Where in the process of writing your code are you stuck?

Comment: Ivr tried several solutions not sure how to acheive it

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66649335/get-exact-color-from-two-colors-with-percentage-in-javascript Plenty of similar questions when you search

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple: find the difference between each color's value, and then multiply each difference by the percentage you want.

I packed it into a function and wrote a small example around it that demonstrates the calculation.

**More detailed explanation**

First you want to set the two values in relation. For this example I will start with these two colors:

```
rgb(120 0 0) and rgb(60 0 0)
```

These two colors can be splittet in their basic ingredients:

```
{r: 120, g: 0, b: 0} and {r: 60, g: 0, b: 0}
```

From here on we will start by iterating the first color object and get the related key from the second color object (f.e. for the "r" value):

```
let start = first["r"];
let end = second["r"];
```

After that we calculate the difference between these two values and multiply it with our target percentage:

```
(start - end) * percentage
```

If the result is negative, we need to convert it into a positive value:

```
Math.abs(offset)
```

Then we just subtract this value from our start value and push it into our result object:

```
result["r"] = (start - offset);
```

After the iteration finished you got all values in your result object.

```js
/**
* Calculation
**/

function calculate(first, second, percentage) {
  let result = {};
  Object.keys(first).forEach((key) => {
    let start = first[key];
    let end = second[key];
    let offset = (start - end) * percentage;
    if(offset >= 0) {
      Math.abs(offset); 
    }
    result[key] = (start - offset);
  });
  return result;
}

/**
* Functions just for demonstration purpose
**/

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
const showcase = document.querySelector('#showcase');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

sumInputs();

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('change', sumInputs);
});

function sumInputs() {
  let sum = {
    "first" : {},
    "second" : {},
    "precentage" : 0
  };
  inputs.forEach((input) => {
    let obj = input.name.split("_")[0];
    let val = input.name.split("_")[1];
    if(val) {
      sum[obj][val] = parseInt(input.value.trim());
    } else {
      sum.precentage = parseFloat(input.value.trim()).toFixed(2);
    }
  });
  let calculation = calculate(sum.first, sum.second, sum.precentage);
  let color = "rgb(" + Object.values(calculation).join(" ") + ")";
  container.style.background = color;
  showcase.innerHTML = color;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 43%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <div>First Color</div>
            r: <input type="number" class="color" name="first_r" value="240"><br>
            g: <input type="number" class="color" name="first_g" value="0"><br>
            b: <input type="number" class="color" name="first_b" value="0"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <div>Second Color</div>
            r: <input type="number" class="color" name="second_r" value="255"><br>
            g: <input type="number" class="color" name="second_g" value="255"><br>
            b: <input type="number" class="color" name="second_b" value="255"><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
        <div>Percentage</div>
        <input type="number" name="percentage" value="0.5" step="0.1" min="0" max="1">
        </div>
        <div class="child">
        <div id="showcase" height="100" width="100" style="background:grey;color:inherit;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer - while code only answers can be helpful, we won't learn anything from "copy - paste - oh look it works"

Comment: Well, it’s basic [linear interpolation](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)…